# MySQL substring to self join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm defining the relationship between the two tables using a join table. I want to arrange them in the order of many overlapping things. Currently, we are using subquery, is there a way to get the same result using join?

```
People                     FoodTable                  PeopleFood
ID |  NAME                 ID |  Food                 ID | PeopleId | FoodId  
1     BOB                  1     Hamberger            1     1           1
2     JOHN                 2     Pizza                2     1           2
3     KATY                 3     Chicken              3     1           3
4     MILLER               4     Salad                4     2           1
5     AMANDA               5     Sushi                5     2           2
                                                      6     2           3
                                                      7     3           2
                                                      8     3           3
                                                      9     4           3
                                                      10    4           5
                                                      11    5           5
```

When the table is defined in this way, I want to arrange food tastes similar to Bob's.
I'm doing it like this now.

```
SELECT people_id, COUNT(people_id) as count 
FROM peopleFood
WHERE food_id IN 
 (SELECT food_id FROM peopleFood
  WHERE people_id = 1)
AND people_id != 1
GROUP BY people_id
ORDER BY count DESC;


-- Result -------------
People_id | count
2           3
3           2
4           1
```

Is there a better way to change this method or use join?
Thank you!!!

Comment: You list 3 tables, but your query does only use a 4:th one.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but can you explain it more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been inconsistent in your use of the table and column names -

Tables - `PeopleFood` in your sample data but you reference `peopleFood` in your query.

Columns - `PeopleId` and `FoodId` in your sample data but you reference `people_id` and `food_id` in your query.

Choose a naming convention and stick to it. Everyone has there own preference but the important thing is to be consistent.

The equivalent query with INNER JOIN instead of your sub-query is -

```sql
SELECT
    `pf2`.`people_id`,
    COUNT(`pf2`.`food_id`) as `count`
FROM `PeopleFood` `pf1`
INNER JOIN `PeopleFood` `pf2`
    ON `pf2`.`people_id` <> `pf1`.`people_id`
    AND `pf2`.`food_id` = `pf1`.`food_id`
WHERE `pf1`.`people_id` = 1
GROUP BY `pf2`.`people_id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

The performance difference between the two queries is unlikely to be noticeable and it might be argued that the intent is clearer in your version with the sub-query.

The surrogate key `ID` on your `PeopleFood` table should be dropped in favour of the compound “natural” primary key on `people_id` and `food_id`.

[The Cost of Useless Surrogate Keys in Relationship Tables](https://blog.jooq.org/the-cost-of-useless-surrogate-keys-in-relationship-tables/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. You're a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join:

```
SELECT p.People_id, COUNT(p.People_id) as count FROM PeopleTable p 
    INNER JOIN FoodTable f 
    ON(p.People_id = f.FoodId) 
    WHERE people = 1 
    GROUP BY p.people_id 
    ORDER BY count DESC;
```

If it helps, please mark it as an accepted answer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But the answer doesn't come out the way I want it to.... Sql error occurs first.... The answer I want is something like Result.